# How to extract all sub-matrices of a bigger one

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix say:

```
Q = [05 11 12 16 25;
     17 18 02 07 10;
     04 23 20 03 01;
     24 21 19 14 09;
     06 22 08 13 15]
```

I would like to list out all the possible 3x3 matrices. Some examples are:

```
11 12 16;
18  2  7;
23 20  3
```

and

```
 5 11 12;
17 18  2;
 4 23 20;
```

etc.. Basically all the possible 3-by-3 matrices.
How do I do it?  I must use a `for` loop?

Answer (score 5):

If you have the [Image Processing Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/), you can use the function [IM2COL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/im2col.html):

```
subMats = im2col(Q,[3 3]);
```

Each column of `subMats` contains the elements of a 3-by-3 matrix extracted from `Q`. Each of these columns can be reshaped into a 3-by-3 matrix as follows:

```
Q1 = reshape(subMats(:,1),[3 3]);  %# Reshape column 1 into a 3-by-3 matrix
```

Comment: for the second part, you can combine all 3-by-3 matrices in the third dimension: `Z = reshape(permute(subMats,[1 3 2]), 3,3,[])`, so that you can access each using `Z(:,:,k)`

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is homework (if not, please forgive me), so here are some hints.

- Draw out the structure of your 5x5 matrix.
- Start in the upper left and draw a 3x3 submatrix within that 5x5.  What are the elements covered by that matrix?
- Go to the upper right.  What elements are covered there?
- Now go to the lower left.  What about there?

Do you see how to cover the whole thing?